# Following other users

Tags: feature-request, users

Can we add an option to profiles, allowing you to follow someone and get an update every time they ask a question? I would like to follow some programmers, but I don't want to have to check every single day to see if I might have missed their code.

Comment: That's a great idea! As a compromise, a lot of us hang out in a [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor) which has a feed of all new questions as they come in. You're welcome to join, if you like.

Comment: @Phrancis I'll consider it... I like the idea of doing that, but i also don't have access to my computer at all times, so i liked the idea of coming on to the site and seeing the red square and seeing that they posted... Or even adding a new tab for following

Comment: This has been [asked multiple times on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75195/follow-a-person), but it's `status-declined`.

Comment: @amon Im talking specifically on Code Review... I like some peoples code, and I would love to get updates on it. Im not looking for a share feature, or anything like that, just somthing on the lines, Hey this user has been asking questoins

Comment: @AmateurProgramer: I don't think this can be a feature for a specific site.  Even then, SE would have to see a *very* good reason for why it should be implemented.

Comment: @Jamal For people like me, who post games and projects, and instead of me having to ping every single user that wanted to see the updated code, they could just follow me and see when i post the new code for the game. Or maybe something on the lines of following a question and then being able to post a branch of that question, theoretically a new question, but it notifies the users who wants to see it.

Comment: @AmateurProgramer you can't ping people who didn't interact with the post... Pings works somewhat *very* different from that ;)

Comment: Edited my answer to add a note about GitHub.

Answer (score 12):

There is a "user feed" button available in everyone's profile. If you have a RSS reader, you can then get updates whenever that user posts something.

Example: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/feeds/user/58582

Additionally, if you're interested in looking at people's code when they do something interesting, there are many users who can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/Zomis), where you can follow them more closely.